# How to Style form radio button input to achieve push button look?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, user-interface

I want to create a donation form that is similar to the one at https://www.charitywater.org/donate ,i believe those blue horizontal buttons are radio buttons that have have been styled with some custom code.

How do I achieve such look without the 'hole' in a normal radio button showing?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far to reproduce the effect you've observed? Have you, for example, right-clicked > inspect element? Have you written any HTML, CSS or JavaScript? Stack Overflow, as a community, loves to help you with your problems but we won't write the code *for* you; please: take the [tour], and read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Comment: <input type="radio">

Comment: If that really is all you've come up with so far then I'm afraid you need to do more research; if you look around the internet you'll find that tutorials exist for this kind of user interface.

Comment: I've searched around the internet,couldn't find it, that's why i came here ,if you have any link, you can please share.

Comment: Asking for links as answers to questions is not allowed on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to hide the browser's default checkbox. This can be done by rendering the default radio button out of sight.

```
[type="radio"]:checked, [type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

The second step is to apply appropriate styles to the corresponding label elements by using the CSS '+' selector which selects all the 'label' elements that are placed immediately after the 'radio' button.

```
[type="radio"]:checked+label, [type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
    /* Your Styles Here */
}
```

Check the attached snippet, I hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.container {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
  border: 1px solid #dfdfd7;
  color: #9b9b94;
  background: #e9eae4;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: #369ff4;
  border-color: #369ff4;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form class="container">
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
    <label for="test1">$50</label>
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test2">$100</label>
    <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test3">$150</label>
</form>
```

Comment: On the contrary, the OP knows quite a lot about HTML and CSS, just that the referred interface looks kind of tricky.

Answer (score -1):

If you look devTools, buttons in this form are made by links `<a>`. You can make it using buttons, divs, spans. it's definitely no radio buttons

Comment: how do i then get the selected values and use as form inputs

Comment: you can add , for example, some clsss, let it be .checked to checked div. After you look for divs with .checked and take their textContent. Or use data-attributes